# Repaint() objects at original position after animation (Java Timer Swing)

Tags: java, swing, animation

I draw a rectangle and I made an animation that changes his position every few seconds. I have an `process()` method that updates the position every second. At the end of animation, I have a `resume()` method that should put the rectangle back to his initial position.

How do I put the rectangle in his first position?

I have an `update(Point)` method in `Rectangle.java` that `repaint()` the object.

Should I save his position somewhere at the beginning, or ? How do I do that?

Comment: *"Should I save his position somewhere at the beginning"* - Yes. *"How do I do that ?"* - It's your code, you know where the animation starts and where it ends...

Comment: I saved its first position in a Point. When I resume(), my rectangle disappears and turns in that point since I update the position of the item with "item.update(p);". 
I think this means I should draw again that rectangle using "rectangle.paint(Graphics2D g)". My problem s that I don't have the g in this animation class. 
Or should I create the object again in the initial point I had ? (I think it's not a good idea).

Comment: You're asking us advice on a API we have no idea about, nor can demonstrate.  As you say, you need to know where it started and you need to reset it's position to that start point.  How you do that comes down to how you API works...which we have no idea about...